# Как удалить атрибут alt и title у картинок на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, атрибуты

Всем привет.

Подскажите, на сайте есть много картинок на каждой странице, и на них мне нужно очистить alt и title в картинках

```
<img class="aligncenter" src="https://***" alt="здесь alt" width="500" height="333" title="здесь title">
```

Можно ли как то это сделать через базу? Решение с помощью которого вообще убрать alt и title не подходит. Нужно именно убрать их из кода.

Comment: Картинка без alt - не валидная

Comment: Знаю про то, что не валидная. Но на сайте есть старые альт и тайтл, которые заполнялись в ручную. Их надо очистить все, а потом уже установить плагин который сам из пропишем по новому шаблону

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если показанный код вставлен в контент, а не генерируется при выводе, то можно воспользоваться любым плагином поиска-замены с поддержкой регулярных выражений. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Или скриптом https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Не забыть предварительно сделать бекап базы.

Но вообще-то `alt` - обязательный атрибут и его удалять не стоит.

Comment: Нам их нужно сначала все очистить, а потом уже поставим плагин для заполнения их по новому шаблону

Comment: Ни один плагин не пропишет в контент. Могут прописать в свойства вложения и потом их вставить. Но это никак не влияет на мой ответ.

Comment: Уже стоит плагин, который заполняет alt и title по шаблону, но заполняет только там, где вообще было пусто.

Comment: Как тогда можно через плагин search regex убрать alt на картинках?